# Is $f$ differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$ then $f'$ is integrable on $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is $f$ differentiable on $[a,b]$  and $f(a)=a$ and $f(b)=b$ then $f'$ integrable on $[a,b]$?

I have just found that there is a differential function $f$ such that $f'$ isn't continuous at $x=0$. I wonder if $\int_a^bf'(t)dt=f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: Hint: What condition(s) on $f'$ need to hold if $f'$ is to be integrable? Are these conditions guaranteed by differentiability of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of an everywhere differentiable function $f$ is not necessarily Riemann integrable, even if $f'$ is bounded. In such cases the set of discontinuity of $f'$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives)